# date field is taking same value as first row in table-AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, frontend

date input is taken by other values as well..below is my html

```
      
           name='form_{{columns.dataId}}'
           ng-init="dateValue = columns.formValue != null ? columns.formValue : ''"
           ng-model="columns.formValue"
           pick-a-date="dateValue">
        </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option

In controller:

```
$scope.dateValues={};

// this will get populated with your dates
// your object ends up looking like this
// $scope.dateValues.12 = "2021-01-01"
// $scope.dateValues.19= "2021-02-01"
// $scope.dateValues.56= "2021-03-01"
```

the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="cell in data.extradata[0].arrayColumns[0].cellData">
         <input class="date_picker"
           ...
           ng-model="dateValues[cell.dataId]"
           ... />
        </div>
```

Comment: hello @john Tyner.. this doesn't solve my question

Comment: i have edited and put my actual code pls check it again

Comment: You removed the ng-repeat loop, but still have your original question of why the date for the first item is getting overwritten. Without the repeat loop or seeing what date values are overwriting the first, it's hard to guess. Also, I am not familiar with the directive you're using, but if for each picker you're setting pick-a-date='date.value' then each picker is accessing a scope object called 'date' and grabbing it's 'value'. That would account for all 3 date pickers showing the same maybe?